# How to update external property while doing a svn merge

Tags: svn, merge, external

I have a private branch that is quite out dated from the trunk. When I do SVN merge from trunk, it seems that it is not updating the revision values of external dependent repositories with new values from the trunk. I am using SVN 1.6.16. Is there a additional step I am missing?

Also svn document seems to indicate that simple merge of head of the trunk with freshly checked out copy of my private branch(which does not have my changes in yet) will cause "removal of trunk changes that never happened on your branch". I just want to bring my private branch up to date with trunk and checkin. I plan to checkin my changes after bringing my private branch up to date with trunk.

Alright, I would really appreciate some light on whats going on: when I do svn merge from trunk directory and do  svn propget svn:externals ., I seem to get updated revision values, but when I do svn up, it does not do anything. Looks like there is a file dir-prop-base whch still holds the old values. Not sure where propget is reading from. So the question is what is propget showing me? and how do I update dir-prop-base file? Another intersting thing, is when i explicitly do propset on one folder, and do svn up on that folder it seems to update the folder, but when i do svn info it still shows old revison value on the folder, although the folder is actually updated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I had to commit the extrenal properties to my private branch and then check out. The correct revisions of external repositories were extracted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `svn merge` simply does not update the working copy of any externals that have revision changes. You can see this by comparing the output of `svn propget svn:externals .` and `svn info <external-directory>`, the two revisions will be out of sync. I consider this a bug in `svn`.

To repair this, just do an `svn checkout <external-url>@<revision> <external-directory>` to match reality to theory again.